# Help Create First Desktop Application - "There was an error launching this application"

Tags: 16.04, .desktop

I created a .sh file "OpenNautilus.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
nautilus;#open Nautilus
```

Then I created a .desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=home/vitor/Dropbox/Ubuntu/ScriptsLinux/OpenNautilus.sh 
Path=home/vitor/Dropbox/Ubuntu/ScriptsLinux
Name=OpenNautilus
```

I saved the .desktop application on `~/.local/share/applications`

Then change the permission to run, but "There was an error launching this application"

I don't know what is wrong... I saved the .desktop file on my desktop.

Using 16.04

Comment: I think both your Exec and Path lines need a `/` before the `home`

Comment: Now it's working!! Do you know if I can write my login "vitor" as an default username here?

Comment: Yes, I will write it in the answer I will post in a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the `Exec=` and `Path=` lines in your `.desktop` file, replacing each `home/vitor` with `~` (a symbol which simply means "the current user's home directory"). When you're done, it should look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=~/Dropbox/Ubuntu/ScriptsLinux/OpenNautilus.sh 
Path=~/Dropbox/Ubuntu/ScriptsLinux
Name=OpenNautilus
```

With that change done, *any* user that has the same directory structure (Dropbox->Ubuntu->ScriptsLinux->OpenNautilus) and `OpenNautilus.sh` file in their home directory can run this .desktop file without making any changes to it.